# What is ssh equivalent read_until and read_very_eager methods at telnet?

Tags: python, ssh, telnet, paramiko

I will write a SSH communicator class on Python. I have telnet communicator class and I should use functions like at telnet. Telnet communicator have read_until and read_very_eager functions.

```
read_until : Read until a given string is encountered or until timeout.
read_very_eager : Read everything that's possible without blocking in I/O (eager).
```

I couldn't find these functions for SSH communicator. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't state it in the question, but I am assuming you are using [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) as per the tag.

- `read_until`: Read until a given string is encountered or until timeout.

  This seems like a very specialized function for a particular high level task. I think you will need to implement this one. You can set a timeout using [paramiko.Channel.settimeout](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.Channel-class.html#settimeout) and then read in a loop until you get either the string you want or a timeout exception.
- `read_very_eager`: Read everything that's possible without blocking in I/O (eager).

  Paramiko doesn't directly provide this, but it does provide primitives for non-blocking I/O and you can easily put this in a loop to slurp in everything that's available on the channel. Have you tried something like this?

  ```
  channel.setblocking(True)
  resultlist = []
  while True:
      try:
          chunk = channel.recv(1024)
      except socket.timeout:
          break
      resultlist.append(chunk)
  return ''.join(resultlist)
  ```

Answer (score 1):

#### Hi there even i was searching solution for the same problem.

I think it might help you ....

one observation, tell me if you find solution.
***I wont get output if i remove 6th line.***

I was actually printing 6th line to know the status, later i found  recv_exit_status() should be called for execution of this code.

```
import paramiko,sys
trans = paramiko.Transport((host, 22))
trans.connect(username = user, password = passwd)
session = trans.open_channel("session")         
session.exec_command('grep -rE print .')  
session.recv_exit_status() 
while session.recv_ready():
    temp = session.recv(1024)
    print temp
```

1.**Read until** >  search for the data you are searching for and break the loop

2.**Read_very_eager** > use the above mentioned code.